# Ошибка при компиляции

Tags: c++

при компиляции приложения получаю

"Unhandled exception at 0x57cb47af (msvcr100d.dll) in Os_pro.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

Что это значит и как его лечить ?

Код (часть кода получает в качестве параметров фомат файлов и начальные пути жестких дисков)

```
enter code here
bool FindByMask(int param)
{
    int i = param+1;
printf("Thread number %i start.\n", i);
for(int i = 0; i < maskCount; )
{
    _TCHAR *drive = drives[param];
    _TCHAR *mask = new _TCHAR[_tcslen(maska[i])];
    _tcscpy(mask, _T("*."));
    _tcscat(mask, maska[i]);
    find(drive, mask);
    ++i;
}
return true;
}

bool find(_TCHAR *drive, _TCHAR *mask)
{
_TCHAR tmp1[MAX_PATH]; 
_TCHAR *tmp2;
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
HANDLE hFileFind;
memset(&findData, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
fstream fstr;

_tcscpy(tmp1, drive);
_tcscat(tmp1, _T("*.*"));
hFileFind = FindFirstFile(tmp1, &findData);
do
{
    if(hFileFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if ((_tcscmp(findData.cFileName, _T(".")) != 0) && (_tcscmp(findData.cFileName, _T("..")) != 0))
        {
            if (findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                _TCHAR newpath[MAX_PATH];
                tmp2 = _tcssubstr(tmp1, 0, _tcslen(tmp1)-4);
                _tcscpy(newpath, tmp2);
                _tcscat(newpath, findData.cFileName);
                _tcscat(newpath, _T("\\"));
                find(newpath, mask);
            }
        }
    }
}
while(FindNextFile(hFileFind, &findData));
FindClose(hFileFind);

_TCHAR *findPath = new _TCHAR[_tcslen(drive)+_tcslen(mask)];
_tcscpy(findPath, drive);
_tcscat(findPath, mask);

hFileFind = FindFirstFile(findPath, &findData);
if(hFileFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        if(!(findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
        {
            tmp2 = _tcssubstr(tmp1, 0, _tcslen(tmp1)-4);
            _TCHAR *fp = new _TCHAR[_tcslen(tmp2) + _tcslen(findData.cFileName)];
            _tcscpy(fp, tmp2);
            _tcscat(fp, findData.cFileName);
            _TCHAR *tmp3 = new _TCHAR[_tcslen(fp)+2];
            _tcscpy(tmp3, _T("\""));
            _tcscat(tmp3, fp);
            _tcscat(tmp3, _T("\""));
            DWORD dwAttr = GetFileAttributes(fp);
            if(dwAttr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE)
            {   
                FILE* f = fopen(".\\list_file.lst", "a+");
                fwprintf_s(f, _T("%s"), tmp3);
                fwprintf_s(f, _T("%s"), _T("\n"));
                SetFileAttributes(fp, dwAttr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE);
                fclose(f);

                _TCHAR *cml;

                cml = new _TCHAR[_tcslen(tmp_1)+_tcslen(tmp3)+_tcslen(tmp_3)];
                _tcscpy(cml, tmp_1);
                _tcscat(cml, tmp_3);
                _tcscat(cml, _T(" "));
                _tcscat(cml, tmp3);
                STARTUPINFO         siStartupInfo;
                PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo;
                memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo));
                memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo));
                siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo);
                CreateProcess(_T(".\\rar.exe"), cml, 0, 0, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, _T(".\\"), &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo);
                WaitForSingleObject( piProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
            }
        }
    }
    while(FindNextFile(hFileFind, &findData));
}
FindClose(hFileFind);
return true;
}`enter code here
```

Comment: Это наверное не при компиляции, а при исполнении программы. Ошибка при чтении памяти там, где читать нельзя. Надо бы код посмотреть для диагностики

Comment: код выложил...

Comment: Вот бы ещё строку кода с ошибкой узнать. У Вас в отладке ошибка обнраруживается? Здесь неясно, откуда переменная `drives`, например. Может быть вот на этой строке крэшится `_TCHAR *drive = drives[param];`

Comment: ошибка в :

cml = new _TCHAR[_tcslen(tmp_1)+_tcslen(tmp3)+_tcslen(tmp_3)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть вот на этой строке крэшится

```
_TCHAR *drive = drives[param];
```

В этом фрагменте, например, Вы недостаточно места для mask выделяете, надо на 2 символа побольше.

```
_TCHAR *mask = new _TCHAR[_tcslen(maska[i])];
_tcscpy(mask, _T("*."));
_tcscat(mask, maska[i]);
```

Здесь нет явной проверки, что хватит места, выделенного для `tmp1`:

```
_tcscpy(tmp1, drive);
_tcscat(tmp1, _T("*.*"));
```

Update:

а где память для tmp_1 выделяется и где оно инициализируется? Возможно, ошибка при попытке вычислить длину строки, когда в поисках завершающего нуля функция длины уходит далеко за пределы выделенной памяти

Update:
то же касается tmp_3

Comment: ошибка в : cml = new _TCHAR[_tcslen(tmp_1)+_tcslen(tmp3)+_tcslen(tmp_3)];

а

Comment: обновил ответ. ничего неизвестно о tmp_1 и tmp_3

Comment: при выделении памяти должна быть константа указана как размер выделяемой памяти, а тут динамика получается, компилятору вычислять приходится всегда.  в C++0x, если вы точно знаете , что функции вернут конст, указываем constexpr, тогда проблем не будет.